# Best practice design DTOs for CRUD ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, crud, dto

I have DTOs Layer to transfer data between API Layer, Data Layer and other
I have a question for DTO design pattern in c#

Example:

```
public class ProductDTO{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public decimal Price {get;set;}
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}
}
```

Should i split this ProductDTO for CRUD?

Example:

```
public class ProductInsertDTO
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int CategoryId {get;set;}
}
```

for ProductDTO (500 byte) and ProductInsertDTO (293 byte) when I transfer data

Comment: But then you end up with 2 objects. Why would you want that?

Comment: I always design with single object, but if I split the dto, is there better on system performance?

Comment: I don't think so, then you will end up creating multiple classes for a single object which will increase the size of the application. Try to normalize and re-use the objects as much as you can.

What you can do in my opinion, create an abstract or Super Class and extend the objects to it, Like an Insert abstract class that way you will be able to extract only the data required for insert.

Comment: Thank you @progrAmmar, I'll try it. you have a sample?

Answer (score 0):

No.  For such small amounts of data, the network overhead is much more of an issue.  The rule of the thumb is: avoid "chatty" communications.  Better exchange more in one call than split it to multiple calls.